# springSecurity Submitting form after session timeout

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have a minor issue with SpringSecurity plugin in Grails application.

The user loads a form and lets the session expire.
After submiting the form, the user is redirected to login page.
After sucessfull login, the user is redirected back to the controller/action that handles the form submit, but the method is now GET instead of POST.

Is it possible to fix this behaviour without allowing the controller/action to be accessible via GET method?

Thanks in advance